# How do you send or forward messages using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

## problem:

1. python-telegram-bot is a package/library that creates bots in telegram using their API. I just want the bot to send a message and forward messages from chat group A to B.
2. When messaging in a group it replies because of the code below. I just want it to send a message.

   update.message.reply_text('Help!')

## Solutions I've tried:

1. I'm an absolute noob in programming and navigating the documentation (https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) hurts my brain.
2. Copied echo bot tutorial (https://www.codementor.io/@karandeepbatra/part-1-how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-in-python-in-under-10-minutes-19yfdv4wrq) which echos what the user sends but couldn't manage to find the right combination of commands in the doc to make it not reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use pass `quote=False` to `reply_text`. See the docs of [`Message.reply_text`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text).

BTW I feel obligated to encourage you to use the resources provided by PTB instead of 3rd party tutorials, since the latter may become outdated more quickly when new versions of PTB are released. You can find links to the official resources at https://python-telegram-bot.org.

---

**Edit:** about forwarding messages: You can use [`Message.forward`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.forward) for that. To make sure that only messages received from group A are forwarded, you can make your handler accept only messages from that chat. For that you can e.g. use [`Filters.chat`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.chat).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you very much but how do you forward messages from a specific group chat to another? In Telethon, I used  `await client.forward_messages("Chat_id", event.message)` the problem is that instead of only forwarding messages from GC A to GC B. It also forwards messages it receives from GC B.

Comment: please have a look at my edit :)

Comment: Yes this works!